# charts.js chart size it's diferente than container setted size

Tags: html, css, chart.js

I'm using a 250x250 canvas element to show a char genereated with charts.js but  the chrat it's bigger than I setted,Do I missed some configuration??This code is mostly the example of the oficial doc but I can't set the size.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="card chart-card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Estadísticas
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <canvas id="myChart" width="250px" height="250px"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>   
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add 2 properties to options object:

```
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
           ticks: {
             beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
   }
}
```

This will fix your issue. But it will fix the height. For width, I think you've to define width of the parent of canvas element like this.

```
<div class="chart">
  <canvas id="myChart" height="250px"></canvas>
</div>
```

```
.chart {
  width: 250px;
}
```

See here for documentation.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html